# Display the images in gridview+iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, gridview, nsxmlparser

I am trying to display the images in grid view i found this code:-[here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/images-display-in-gridview-on-iphone/)
But now the images which i have to display is coming through webservice.
I want that as the data comes from web-service simultaneously the data should be displayed in cell of the table.
Is there any way.Please help me..

Comment: Why don't you customize the code of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html lazy table images ?

Comment: What web services you are using and what all data are you fetching from server ?

Comment: It looks similar to one of your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937361/iphoneuiscrollview-or-to-use-uitableview-to-display-image-in-matrix-format

Answer (score 1):

In the given sample code, function `loadView` is used to populate your images, there you can parse your webservice and populate your array.

After your webservice is parsed just reload your table. 
Dont forget to use activity indicator
Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, they are populating a single row, where you can use [Asynchronous image loading concept](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/). Since you are loading more images in a single row, you need to apply some logic to get this done.

you will need to manage it asynchronously since there can be many images and synchronous loading will freeze your app.